# Generating random color using python id() function

Tags: python, python-2.7, colors

**Scenario:**
As part of a 3D game engine, I want to implement pixel-perfect "mouse picking" (basically allowing the user to click on different 3D models in the scene). One way to do this is to render the scene to a texture, where each object is randomly colored with a single, flat color. Then, when the user clicks on the screen, I simply get the color underneath the cursor and I would know which object I clicked on in the scene. Naturally, I want to ensure that each model has assigned to it a unique color. The color itself is not too important as it is never rendered onto the screen.

**Actual Question:**
Since I have a `Model` class, when I create different model objects in python, I know that each one will have a different `id()` value in python. Given this unique memory address value, is there a way I can go about generating a unique RGB floating point color triplet?

---

**Edit:**
Following @Jack Witherell's answer, here is some code that implements that idea:

```
def get_pick_color(model):
    model_id = id(model)
    r = int(model_id/(256**3))
    g = int(model_id%(256**3)/(256**2))
    b = int(model_id%(256**2)/256)
    a = int(model_id%256)
    return (r, g, b, a)

for model in range(10):
    print model, id(model), get_pick_color(model)
```

**Sample Output:**

```
0 50096352 (2, 252, 104, 224)
1 50096328 (2, 252, 104, 200)
2 50096304 (2, 252, 104, 176)
3 50096280 (2, 252, 104, 152)
4 50096256 (2, 252, 104, 128)
5 50096232 (2, 252, 104, 104)
6 50096208 (2, 252, 104, 80)
7 50096184 (2, 252, 104, 56)
8 50096160 (2, 252, 104, 32)
9 50096136 (2, 252, 104, 8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on what kind of value the id format is in. If you know that the value is simply an integer, you could try setting r to id()%256 and g to id()/256 for color values. This would accommodate for different values for about 65536 different object ids.

For example, if you had 1,103 objects, and you clicked on 1098, r would be equal to 74 and g would be equal to 4 because:

1098%256 would be equal to 74
(1098-256-256-256-256=74)

and 1098/256=4 after it's been rounded down.

You can extend that to two more color values, blue and alpha, if applicable. your color value for each pixel will look a bit like this

(id()/16777216,(id()%16777216)/65536,(id()%65536)/256,id()%2‌​56)

assuming id() outputs the number 54421704, the color value will equal

(3,62,104,200)

which should be unique to the number 54421704

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Typically the numbers returned by the built-in`id()` function are a little larger. Testing in IDLE just now with python 2.7, I created a variable and got back an id of `54421704L` (as a random example). Using your approach, I would get a red component of 200 and a green one of 212584. The green might be a little too high to work with; ideally I would like to keep it under 256 like the red one and normalize the result. Also, I would like to use the blue channel as well. Is there a way to use that one instead to increase the number of supported model objects even further?

Comment: Oh of course! Easily. If you use blue and have it store id()%65536 then it will increase by 1 every time that you move past a multiple of 65536. This would give you 16,777,216 possibilities. If you then store a fourth value, and set it using id()%16777216 (you'll need to be able to draw something like alpha to the texture) then you'll get 16,777,216*256 possibilities. make sure to set the value that divides by the second exponent from the max to be equal to that exponent. (in my original example, 256 was the exponent, and b was storing the values smaller than id()/[the exponent 256]

Comment: your color value for each pixel will look a bit like this
 `(id()/16777216,(id()%16777216)/65536,(id()%65536)/256,id()%256)` 
assuming id() outputs the number `54421704`, the color value will equal (3,62,104,200) which should be unique to the number 54421704

Comment: Perfect! I added a sample that implements your answer to my question. It is a pretty solution, especially when you use exponents :). Update your answer with the info in your comments and I will go ahead and accept it!